# Any pointers on building a clock in clock out web app

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to build a clock in clock out web app, which saves time to the database, but since i am new to php js, I just need pointers or the right direction. Reading material or something like that would be helpful too. I tried google but didnt find what i was looking for. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Split your task in small pieces and start googling again. For example see how to write to database, see how to do AJAX requests and these kind of stuff. Your question is too broad and I doubt that someone is going to help you for what you've written

Comment: Oh I thought it was a straightforward question, but I will keep that in mind. I just needed someone else's opinion before I start the project. E.g, how would you think of this problem as and such. Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't explain where you are stuck or what you have achieved so far, I cannot understand what you are looking for; Anyway i just put as an example, How to display a Clock using JavaScript. This gets time from the client computer and displays it.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Clock</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showtime(){
    if (!document.all & !document.getElementById)
    return
    thelement=document.getElementById? document.getElementById("DigitalClock"): document.all.DigitalClock
    var Digital=new Date()
    var hours=Digital.getHours()
    var minutes=Digital.getMinutes()
    var seconds=Digital.getSeconds()
    var dn="PM"
    if (hours<12)
    dn="AM"
    if (hours>12)
    hours=hours-12
    if (hours==0)
    hours=12
    if (minutes<=9)
    minutes="0"+minutes
    if (seconds<=9)
    seconds="0"+seconds
    var ctime=hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds+" "+dn
    thelement.innerHTML= ctime
    setTimeout("showtime()",1000)
}
window.onload=showtime

var activeElemId;
function activateItem(elemId) {
     document.getElementById(elemId).className="current";
     if(null!=activeElemId) {
       document.getElementById(activeElemId).className="";
     }
     activeElemId=elemId;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
Digital Clock 
<div class="panel-body" id="DigitalClock" style="font-size:25px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have no started it, but I was thinking about it and just wanted to know how would other people, experienced people, think about it. However, I appreciate your time and the code you have provided. Could you tell me what does !document.all do, and this setTimeout("showtime()",1000)

Comment: !document.all is very same as !document.getElementById, it checks whether document elements are exists or not. !document.all is used for very old browsers including older versions of IE. But now it does not make any sense to newer browsers. setTimeout("showtime()",1000)  means, it calls showtime() function every 1000 milliseconds.